# How to recover Gmail Id from the API key

Tags: gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I created a Gmail account for development and enabled the APIs for developer console. I generated one API key which I used in my application but now I forgot the Id that I used. I have to upgrade the plan for APIs but for this, I need the Gmail Id. Is there any way I can get the Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So after I have tried different options I was standing in the same position. So I dig all into my accounts and luckily my recovery email id was one of them, so I searched for all the emails from Google having the subject as `Security your linked Google Account` and sender as `no-reply@accounts.google.com` this will give you all the Ids associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround to fix the issue is to contact "Google API support team"

Just Go to the given link and raise your issue. They will assist you further steps to follow. https://support.google.com/googleapi/?hl=en#topic=7014522

I hope this will help you :)